# Assigns method returns nil in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am doing my testing with mocks and stubs but I keep getting nil in my output. I am not sure if it's the problem with the assigns method. Could I also know how I should debug this kind of problem? I am using rspec-rails 3.5.2 Thank you.

The failing test:

```
describe 'guest user' do
   describe 'GET index' do
     let(:achievement) { instance_double(Achievement) }

     before do
       allow(Achievement).to receive(:get_public_achievements) { [achievement] }
     end

     it 'assigns public achievements to template' do
       get :index
       expect(assigns(achievement)).to eq([achievement])
     end
   end
end
```

The index action in the controller

```
 def index
   @achievements = Achievement.get_public_achievements
 end
```

The get_public_achievements in the achievement model

```
  def self.get_public_achievements
     // empty method it's fine
  end
```

The error:

```
1) AchievementsController guest user GET index assigns public achievements to template
 Failure/Error: expect(assigns(achievement)).to eq([achievement])

   expected: [#<InstanceDouble(Achievement) (anonymous)>]
        got: nil

   (compared using ==)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`assigns` is keyed by symbols. Should be

```
expect(assigns(:achievements)).to eq([achievement])
```

Comment: thanks this solved the problem. However, I am still not sure when to use the pluralised form or a singular form. Is there a convention?

Comment: @JeffreyYong: sure, there is a convention. Do you know what assigns check does? It asserts something about variables you set in the controller. So use whatever name you set in the controller.

Comment: Sorry for the naive question, I am very new to rails programming.

Comment: thank you very much. That clears it up. I am actually reading Michael Hartl's book. It's really detailed but I can't remember everything I have read. I try to do more side projects myself to remember the things that I have read from the book. Thank you!

Comment: SO only allowed me to accept it after 5 minutes. I have done it now :) Thanks!